# rake task on gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rake

I have a rake task for a series of rspecs as follows...

```
require 'spec/rake/spectask'
require 'joliscrapper'

namespace :spec do

  desc "Web scraping files"
  task :scrapers => :environment do
    Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new do |t|
      t.spec_opts = ['--options', "\"#{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/spec.opts\""]
      t.spec_files = FileList['spec/scrapers/*_spec.rb']
      puts t
    end
  end

end
```

My question is how to get out put as usual from an Rspec... now it outputs nothing... I'd like to find any errors and generate an email if one occurs.

adding:

```
  t.warning = true
  t.verbose = true
```

does't seem to have the desired effect either.

http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.12/classes/Spec/Rake/SpecTask.html

Comment: if i take away the "task :scrapers => :environment do", it outputs errors.  The gems don't load properly so they all fail, but i get output.  I get no output currently except: #<Spec::Rake::SpecTask:0x105ec15e8>

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written will create the spec task when `rake spec:scrapers` is called and be finished, which isn't what you want I think.

Try:

```
namespace :spec do

  desc "Web scraping files"  
  Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new :scrapers do |t| #creates the spec task with the name :scrapers
    t.spec_opts = ['--options', "\"#{RAILS_ROOT}/spec/spec.opts\""]
    t.spec_files = FileList['spec/scrapers/*_spec.rb']
  end 
  task :scrapers => :environment #adds environment as a prereq
end
```

Comment: ok, that seems to work.  But i get an error because my gem is not included.  I tried adding require 'somegem' for my gem but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: For your gem, unless you have installed it on your machine, `require 'foo'` won't work. You need to either add your project's lib to the load path, or require the file more explicitly, like so: `require File.expand_path(__FILE__)+'/../lib/joliscrapper'`